# sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint :: Connections to the domain are not allowed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

Lately Microsoft has released [sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/azure-sql-database-external-rest-endpoints-integration-public-preview/#comments) which seems very straight forward:

```
declare @ret as int, @response as nvarchar(max);

exec @ret = sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint 
    @method = 'GET',
    @url = 'https://api.publicapis.org/entries',
    @response = @response output;
    
select @ret as ReturnCode, @response as Response;
```

I've been trying to query [test REST endpoints](https://apipheny.io/free-api/) and they all return the error:

```
Msg 31612, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sys.sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint_internal, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
Connections to the domain api.publicapis.org are not allowed.
```

As anyone been able to use this stored procedure?

Comment: Reading the link mentions it only works for calling Azure services. Seems like an anti-feature, anyway, API access shouldn't be happening from within the DB layer.

Comment: I think the idea is to call some azure function (and i guess lose money), and the function should call out to the actual API

Comment: The reason to go through an allow-listed domain is for security, for example to avoid DNS poisoning or CSRF attacks. If you don't want to use Azure Functions, you can use Azure API Management. Both are free up to 1M request per month.

Comment: @mauridb, and that would be like whitelisting domains?

Comment: Azure API Management act as a gateway and will call any service on your behalf. So Azure SQL can call API Management (which is a trusted service) which in turn can call any REST endpoint, anywhere (and allows you to put security in place too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed with @AlwaysLearning and @siggemannen there are only specific endpoints are allowed to call the Rest API.

> As per [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-invoke-external-rest-endpoint-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&tabs=request-headers#allowed-endpoints) below are some specific endpoints that are allowed.
> [image]

The workaround can be to use the azure function to call the rest Api and then get call this azure function from SQL and get response code and response.

- I create a sample python function to call the API

**My sample init.py file:**

```py
import logging
import requests
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
output = requests.get('https://reqres.in/api/users/2')
return func.HttpResponse(output.content)
```

**Output of Function:**

[image]

- Calling this function from Azure SQL

**Query:**

```sql
declare @ret as  int, @response as  nvarchar(max);
exec @ret = sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint
@method =  'GET',
@url =  '<function-url>',
@response = @response output;
select @ret as ReturnCode, @response as Response;
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: When you say "Calling this function from Azure SQL" I don' see `HttpTrigger1` mentioned in the code. How can T-SQL call that python script?

Comment: in the @url I am passing Function URL my sample URL format `https://<functionapp-name>.azurewebsites.net/api/httptrigger1`

Comment: Thank you. It would be nice to pass parameters from the T-SQL code. This looks like an anti-feature

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani you can pass parameters, either via URL, QueryString or HTTP Headers, as you would normally do with any REST call